# Soma de arrays dentro de array

Tags: php, array, wordpress

Eu tenho um array que ele recebe outros arrays. Nesse exemplo abaixo existem 3 arrays principais e cada um deles tem outros arrays. Oq eu preciso é somar o valor de cada array para cada item igual.

Por exemplo, para o item Cálcio preciso pegar o valor dele em cada array e somar e criar uma array nova.

Esse é o array que tenho:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Cálcio
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => calcio
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Calorias
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => calorias
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Carboidrato
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => carboidrato
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Ferro
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => ferro
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Lipídio
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => lipidio
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Proteína
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => proteina
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Sódio
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => sodio
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Vitamina
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => vitamina
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Vitamina C
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => vitamina-c
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Vitamina D
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => vitamina-d
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Cálcio
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => calcio
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Calorias
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => calorias
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Carboidrato
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => carboidrato
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Ferro
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => ferro
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Lipídio
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => lipidio
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Proteína
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => proteina
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Sódio
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => sodio
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Vitamina
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => vitamina
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Vitamina C
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => vitamina-c
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Vitamina D
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => vitamina-d
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Cálcio
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => calcio
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Calorias
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => calorias
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Carboidrato
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => carboidrato
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Ferro
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => ferro
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Lipídio
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => lipidio
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Proteína
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => proteina
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Sódio
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => sodio
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Vitamina
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => vitamina
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Vitamina C
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => vitamina-c
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Vitamina D
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => vitamina-d
                )

        )

)
```

Aqui é o array que quero gerar:

```
Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Cálcio
                    [valor] => 3
                   
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Calorias
                    [valor] => 3
                    
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Carboidrato
                    [valor] => 3
                   
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Ferro
                    [valor] => 3
                    
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Lipídio
                    [valor] => 3
                    
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Proteína
                    [valor] => 3
                   
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Sódio
                    [valor] => 3
                   
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Vitamina
                    [valor] => 3
                   
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Vitamina C
                    [valor] => 3
                    
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Vitamina D
                    [valor] => 3
                    
                )

        )
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Poste o que você já tentou fazer para tentar somar, pois tem N abordagens para seu caso.

Comment: Opa @HelisonSantos, tudo bom? Cara eu tentei fazer umas coisas com foreach, mas não entendi a lógica que poderia usar. Então em ultimo caso vim pedir ajuda aqui para dar uma luz. Acredito que vou ter que usar alguma função de array do php. Se vc puder me ajudar, ficarei grado. Já quebrei a cabeça! rsrsrs

Comment: Não publique soluções no campo de pergunta. Se quiser adicionar uma solução use o campo de respostas.

Comment: @AugustoVasques retirei a solução. Não sabia que não era uma boa. Valeu pela dica!

Comment: Se ao menos passasse o array com um array php valido poderia até apresentar uma solução mais simples usando [funções php de arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.array.php), mas com o retorno `print_r()` eu teria que reescrever elemento por elemento e chave por chave  dando me muito trabalho

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solução-- Com ajuda da resposta do Daniel consegui modificar o código dele e fazer o meu próprio que deu certo!!

primeiro de tudo é que tenho esse array

```
$itens
```

No array $itens tenho isso:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Cálcio
                    [valor] => 3
                    [slug] => calcio
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Calorias
                    [valor] => 3
                    [slug] => calorias
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Carboidrato
                    [valor] => 3
                    [slug] => carboidrato
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Ferro
                    [valor] => 3
                    [slug] => ferro
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Lipídio
                    [valor] => 3
                    [slug] => lipidio
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Proteína
                    [valor] => 3
                    [slug] => proteina
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Sódio
                    [valor] => 3
                    [slug] => sodio
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Vitamina
                    [valor] => 3
                    [slug] => vitamina
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Vitamina C
                    [valor] => 3
                    [slug] => vitamina-c
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Vitamina D
                    [valor] => 3
                    [slug] => vitamina-d
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Cálcio
                    [valor] => 2
                    [slug] => calcio
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Calorias
                    [valor] => 2
                    [slug] => calorias
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Carboidrato
                    [valor] => 2
                    [slug] => carboidrato
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Ferro
                    [valor] => 2
                    [slug] => ferro
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Lipídio
                    [valor] => 2
                    [slug] => lipidio
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Proteína
                    [valor] => 2
                    [slug] => proteina
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Sódio
                    [valor] => 2
                    [slug] => sodio
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Vitamina
                    [valor] => 2
                    [slug] => vitamina
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Vitamina C
                    [valor] => 2
                    [slug] => vitamina-c
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Vitamina D
                    [valor] => 2
                    [slug] => vitamina-d
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Cálcio
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => calcio
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Calorias
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => calorias
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Carboidrato
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => carboidrato
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Ferro
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => ferro
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Lipídio
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => lipidio
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Proteína
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => proteina
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Sódio
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => sodio
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Vitamina
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => vitamina
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Vitamina C
                    [valor] => 1
                    [slug] => vitamina-c
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Vitamina D
                    [valor] => 2
                    [slug] => vitamina-d
                )

        )

)
```

Então a solução foi primeiro criar uma array so para os itens, chamei de $itens_novo;

```php
// Aqui faço um loop para criar o array so com os itens
$itens_novo = [];
        foreach ($itens as $item) {


            foreach ($item as  $value) {


                $itens_novo[] = $value['item'];
            }
        }

//Porém o array de cima está com itens duplicados, então uso a função array_unique para criar um array apenas com itens únicos.

        $itens_novo = array_unique($itens_novo);

//Aqui que vem a solução que o Daniel me ajudou. Criar um array de resultados com loop dentro de loop.

        $resultados = [];
        foreach ($itens_novo as $i) :
            $valor_total = 0;
            foreach ($itens as $A) :
                foreach ($A as $a) :
                    # Um loop dentro de um loop dentro de um loop:
                    # é um programa bem lento pra arrays muitos grandes ou com vários itens
                    if ($a["item"] == $i) :
                        $valor_total += $a["valor"];
                    endif;
                endforeach;
            endforeach;
            array_push($resultados, array("item" => $i, "valor" => $valor_total));
        endforeach;
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```php
# listar cada item que existe
$itens = [];
foreach($Array[0] as $a):
    array_push( $itens, $a["item"]);
endforeach;

$resultados = [];
foreach($itens as $i):
    $valor_total = 0;
    foreach($Array as $A):
        foreach( $A as $a):
            # Um loop dentro de um loop dentro de um loop:
            # é um programa bem lento pra arrays muitos grandes ou com vários itens
            if( $a["item"] == $i):
                $valor_total += $a["valor"];
            endif;
        endforeach;
    endforeach;
    array_push( $resultados, array( "item"=>$i, "valor"=>$valor_total ) );
endforeach;

print_r($resultados);
```

Deve haver um método mais eficiente, mas eu desconheço.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Daniel, muito obrigado. Sua lógica deu certo. Só tive que mudar o começo. Vou postar como eu fiz!